# Adding value to parameter in C# (asp.net) to be saved in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, parameters, sql-insert

I am quite new to ASP.NET and I am making my first application for my school project and I have one problem.

I have my database for adding files and pictures. I used a `SqlDataSource` and `DataList`, so I generate insert, update and delete automatically. In code-behind C#, I wrote code for adding images directly to database and file with path that goes to database, but I don't know how to add value (path) to parameter so it could all be saved together. What command should I use?

Maybe it is stupid question, but I don't have anyone to ask. Sorry If my code is a little bit funny looking here in this window`enter code here`

Here is my C#

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
   FileUpload kontrola = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload2");

   if (kontrola.PostedFile != null && kontrola.PostedFile.FileName != "")
   {
      BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(kontrola.PostedFile.InputStream);
      myImage = reader.ReadBytes(kontrola.PostedFile.ContentLength);
   }

   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter uploadData =  
   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@image",System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);               
   uploadData.Value = myImage;

   e.Command.Parameters.Add(uploadData);

   FileUpload kontrola2 = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");

   //Get Filename from fileupload control
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(kontrola2.PostedFile.FileName);
   //Save images into Images folder
   kontrola2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/files/" + kontrola2.FileName));

   string valp = "files/" + kontrola2.FileName; //  I am not sure if this is right

   //e.Command.Parameters.Add["@data_file"].Value = valp; // this is not right, but this part I don't know
}
```

and this is my markup in `aspx`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:repository_dbConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [data]" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [data] WHERE [id] = @id" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [data] ([data_set_name], [abstract], [source], [multivariate], [unvariate], [sequentional], [time_series], [text], [domain_theory], [clasification], [regression], [clustering], [casual_discovery], [categorical], [integer], [real], [life_sciences], [physical_sciences], [cs_engineering], [social_sciences], [business], [game], [other], [matrix], [non_matrix], [yes], [no], [num_istances], [num_attributes], [relevant_info], [attribute_info], [relevant_papers], [citation_request], [data_file], [image], [date], [approval]) VALUES (@data_set_name, @abstract, @source, @multivariate, @unvariate, @sequentional, @time_series, @text, @domain_theory, @clasification, @regression, @clustering, @casual_discovery, @categorical, @integer, @real, @life_sciences, @physical_sciences, @cs_engineering, @social_sciences, @business, @game, @other, @matrix, @non_matrix, @yes, @no, @num_istances, @num_attributes, @relevant_info, @attribute_info, @relevant_papers, @citation_request, @data_file, @image, GetDate(), @approval)" 
    UpdateCommand...
    oninserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserting">
   <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
   </DeleteParameters>
   <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="data_set_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="abstract" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="source" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="multivariate" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="unvariate" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sequentional" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="time_series" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="text" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="domain_theory" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="clasification" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="regression" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="clustering" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="casual_discovery" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="categorical" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="integer" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="real" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="life_sciences" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="physical_sciences" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="cs_engineering" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="social_sciences" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="business" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="game" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="other" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="matrix" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="non_matrix" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="yes" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="no" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="num_istances" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="num_attributes" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="relevant_info" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="attribute_info" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="relevant_papers" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="citation_request" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="data_file" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="approval" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've specified the Insert parameters in the SqlDataSource, so they'll already exist in the Parameters collection. You only need to call:

```
e.Command.Parameters["@data_file"].Value = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in front-End aspx put edit text and FileUpload 
after that in the back-End C# use same this

```
  var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YesserDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO testOne (DocNo,DocSysNo,DocTypeID,DocDate,DocDateHj,DocSubjectID,DocDestinaionID,DocSoureceID,DocConfidentionyID,DocPriorityID,DocRemarks,DocAttributes) VALUES (@DocNo,@DocSysNo,@DocTypeID,@DocDate,@DocDateHj,@DocSubjectID,@DocDestinaionID,@DocSoureceID,@DocConfidentionyID,@DocPriorityID,@DocRemarks,@DocAttributes)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNo", DocNo );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSysNo", DocSysNo );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocTypeID", DocTypeID );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDate", DocDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDateHj", DocDateHj);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSubjectID", DocSubjectID );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocDestinaionID",DocDestinaionID );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSoureceID",DocSoureceID );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocConfidentionyID", DocConfidentionyID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocPriorityID", DocPriorityID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocRemarks", DocRemarks);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocAttributes", DocAttributes);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttachFile", FileUpload1.TemplateControl);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
```